# how to connect crystal reports with visual fox pro

Tags: crystal-reports, database-connection, foxpro, visual-foxpro

i would like to ask how to connect the crystal report with Visual Fox pro.

In connecting i mean the crystal report having to connect directly to visual fox pro .DBF without any coding on Visual Fox pro.

Is there any step like on how to connect stored procedures in SQL SERVER?

i know how to connect crystal reports to SQL SERVER, but i don't know how to connect crystal reports to visual fox pro .DBF

maybe this is a very simple question to you. kindly be understanding sirs.
thanks in advance sirs and mams!

Comment: Give a look at this article, the second question explains how to connect crystal to foxpro http://www.ml-consult.co.uk/foxst-19.htm

Comment: yeah but, how do you really connect them? there's no real explanation on how to connect it? i need a step by step procedure to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this a few times, but it likely depends on your version of Crystal Reports.

In the more recent version,

> in the Database Expert > Create New Connection > OLE DB(ADO) > Make
>   New Connection

Now, on the screen that appears,

> select Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLEDB Provider and click next

For the database name, you want the folder that the file resides in, NOT the whole path

.
Finally,

> select the table you want to use and proceed as you would with any
>   other data source.